# Creating UI Themes for Windows Themes

Tags: windows, winforms

Is there any way to create UI components like Telerik,DevExpress for Windows Forms. Are there any specific namespaces for this in the .NET framework . If there any please add them in here.

Comment: Where have you looked so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest Winforms comes to theming is child controls inheriting their parents' UI properties by default. That's pretty blunt though. 3rd party control sets do allow theming but you're not going to see anything like it in the stock .NET BCL.

But, with some clever subclassing you could create your own set of "themed" controls. Assuming you don't want to spend $ on a 3rd party package. You could pick a set of standard Winforms controls, inherit each one with your own class e.g. KalgTextBox, KalgForm etc.
Then have each class implement an interface like IKalgThemedUi with a single method like SetTheme that takes a KalgTheme object and passes it on to its children, if any, or a single property like KalgTheme which on the getter would do exactly what the method would do. The KalgTheme object would of course contain all the theming information for your control set. The theming could be as simple or complex as you want.

A couple of theme/skinning code examples:

- [A nice but advanced framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33716/Fancy-Windows-Forms#themes)
- [A simple but not so great framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7566/Net-Win-Forms-Themes)
- [A CSS-like implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14814/StylesSheetManager-A-CSS-like-component-for-WinFor)

Comment: @KalG: I added a couple of links to CodeProject articles that look promising. Happy coding!